# Rescale Tensorboard Summaries-Plot

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

My loss function has two outliers (no idea why, is below 1, and suddenly after 3.000 steps shows a 6000). So nothing is visible, as all is a straight line with that one outlier rescaling the whole thing. How can I rescale this?

thx

Comment: did you try `alt` (or `option`) then scrolling/zooming with your mouse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can zoom in TensorBoard by dragging on the chart.

You can also make the display larger by pressing the small blue box in the lower-left corner of the chart.

Comment: Dragging it is!! Thx

Comment: Seriously, they should implement panning.

Comment: Panning is implemented - shift + click. What I'm curious to know is how to zoom *out*. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

To be clear, whith TensorFlow you just have to select a zone in the graph that you want to zoom in.[image]

Comment: How do you zoom back out?

Comment: To zoom back, just double-click on the graph and you should come back to the initial state. Not really a zoom back, but once you are back you could zoom in again by selecting another region of interest.

Comment: Is there a way to zoom OUT?

Answer (score 2):

For me you just need to do `alt` (or `option`) then zoom in our out with your mouse. If you try to just scroll/zoom with your mouse on the plot it will even tell you that explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set the axis limits directly for graphs in the time series tab (works with my tensorboard version, 2.5.0).
Just hover with the mouse over the wanted axis and an edit icon will appear. press it and it will let you set the max and min values for that axis.
[image of icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G0YY.png)

Comment: FYI, the relevant PR is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/pull/4711).